# Is it possible to have environment variables in the path of the working directory : PS1?

Tags: linux, bash, prompt, ps1

I am on Lubuntu and I am using bash. My PS1 (in .bashrc) is :

```
PS1="\w> "
```

I like it because I need to paste the working directory all the time.
The problem is that the path is always very long and since I use terminator I only have half of my screen's width available to display it... it is ugly and annoying.
My command prompt looks like that :

```
/this/is/a/very/long/path/that/i/want/to/make/shorter >
```

I'd like to set in my environment variables :

```
$tiavl=/this/is/a/very/long
```

And then I'll get :

```
$tiavl/path/that/i/want/to/make/shorter >
```

The goal is to have something shorter in the command prompt but I still want to be able to copy paste it and do :

```
cd $tiavl/path/that/i/want/to/make/shorter
```

It is a bit like with $HOME :

```
~/path/that/i/want/to/make/shorter  >
```

I know where I am and I can copy paste the ~.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a little helper function, as below (use `/home` as an example prefix path):

```
~ > pwd
/home/me
~ > tiavl=/home
~ > prompt_path () { echo ${1/#$tiavl/\$tiavl}; }
~ > export PS1="\$(prompt_path \w) > "
$tiavl/me >
```

This uses a simple string manipulation function (see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for lots of examples) in the function to replace the initial part of the path with a literal `$tiavl` if it matches.

Here's a demo of how to update that function for several paths.

```
#! /bin/sh

path1=/home
path2=/usr
path3=/var

prompt_path() {
    local path
    path="${1/#$path1/\$path1}"
    path="${path/#$path2/\$path2}"
    path="${path/#$path3/\$path3}"
    echo "$path"
}

prompt_path $HOME
prompt_path /usr/local
prompt_path /var/tmp
```

Comment: Seems good to me. A question : if I want to have several prefix paths, I can not see how it can work. I write some bash scripts but I am not confident with string manipulation... I am reading your link.

Comment: The demo of Mat completely answers my question. Thanks Mat. I was understanding the substitution with the link he gave.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy paste in the terminal, you can just use $PWD environment variable which will always show you the working directory.

```
echo $PWD
```

shows the working directory.

Comment: It was more like after changing of directory several times or copy paste from a different terminal. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @mthpvg Are you aware of the `pushd` and `popd` tools?

Comment: Thanks for that, always thought it was like "cd -"... it is not. But it is only working within one terminal. I am gonna use it anyway :).

Answer (score 0):

So basically you make a bash script :

```
prompt_path
```

which contains :

```
#! /bin/sh
path="${1/#$path1/\$path1}"
path="${path/#$path2/\$path2}"
path="${path/#$path3/\$path3}"
echo "$path"
```

You place it in a folder like :

```
~/.local/bin
```

You give x right to your script :

```
chmod u+x prompt_path
```

In your ~/.bashrc :

1 - you change PS1 to :

```
PS1="\$(prompt_path \w) > "
```

2 - you add those lines :

```
export path1=/home
export path2=/usr
export path3=/var
```

3 - you indicate so that you can call your script from anywhere:

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Finally you source your .bashrc :

```
. ~/.bashrc
```