# the use of the dollar sign, '$' in Linux or C++ (highly likely Linux)

Tags: linux, command-line

If someone tells me to 'save the file to $PWD', what does this mean?

Does '$' sign largely used among linux users to represent something?

For your information, I got this phrase from my instruction sheet from basic C++ course that is held in linux lab.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/493205/is-it-possible-to-have-environment-variables-in-the-path-of-the-working-director/493217#493217

Comment: @random comment answer one part of your question. (about what does this mean)

$WHATEVER is a variable. You can store practically anything in there. In the case of $PWD - it refers to the working directory

Answer (score 6):

In most shells – sh, bash, csh..., – the `$NAME` syntax denotes variables (similar to `%NAME%` in Windows cmd.exe); usually environment variables, but several of them are internal to the shell.

(But note that this convention also sometimes extends to written instructions, where *you* would be expected to mentally substitute the values when reading the text.)

Similarly, some programming languages – PHP, Perl – also use `$name` for variable names.

---

In your example, `$PWD` is an automatic envvar that expands to the current directory's path:

```
> cd /etc/modprobe.d
> echo $PWD
/etc/modprobe.d
```

So to save a file "to $PWD" you wouldn't need to do anything special; trying to open a bare filename with no path *already* uses the current directory.

If you had been given a different, custom variable, you would have to use `getenv("NAME")` to obtain its value in a C++ program.

You can use `env` to see all environment variables, but also check the shell's documentation for a few unusual ones.